# build chain of ajax query and run them

Tags: jquery, performance

I have next code and as I know this is not so good,

```
 var addrIds = [1000,1001,1003,1004,1005];


 $.each(addrIds, function (index, adr) {
                                var data = { "addressId": parnetId, "parentId": adr };
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '/Change',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    contentType: 'application/json',
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    cache: false,
                                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                                    success: function (result) {

                                    },
                                    complete: function (e, xhr, settings) {
                                        switch (e.status) {
                                            case 200:
                                                break;
                                            default:
                                                {
                                                    console.log(e.statusText);                                              
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }); 
                        });
```

is it possible to re factor this and create chain of ajax requests

Comment: Just send your entire data to the server trough a single request and let the server do the "change" for-each one of them. Or that is not feasible with your current environment? If it's so, then what do you understand trough chaining ajax request, cause sending them async is the way you want them, as you are doing now. If you are thinking of waiting for each request to send another one is just ... not right!

Comment: if it not possible to do in one request ?

Comment: If it's not possible i would go with sending requests the way you do, but we have a problem if we want to do something with the response from each request as a whole. 

Then we need to implement a mechanism trough which we are notified when the last request was done, and i am not saying that the last request is the one you fire last, it's the one that is completed the last.

Also take in consideration that every browser has a maximum concurrent Ajax request to a domain, and vary from 2 in IE7 and 6 in Chrome.

Comment: Anyway you can check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066002/sending-one-ajax-request-at-a-time-from-a-loop/5066125#5066125) maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make 1 ajax call with a separated string like that :

1001;1002;1003

And in your server method you just call an explode method to do stuff on all your addrIds

Comment: if it not possible to do in one request ?

Comment: Why exactly is it not possible ?

Comment: for example this is not possible to make this changes, or this is some external service

Comment: Anyway, I don't think that doing an ajax query in a loop is a good thing for any reason.

Comment: There are situations when you want this. For example when you have a multiple file upload and want them to be send async.